# Read POST parameters from apache module

Tags: c, apache, http-post, apache-modules

I'm trying to read POST parameters from an apache c module.

Here's the code I'm using :

```
/* Include the required headers from httpd */
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_core.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "http_request.h"
#include "http_config.h"

#include "apr_strings.h"
#include "apr_network_io.h"
#include "apr_dbd.h"
#include <apr_file_info.h>
#include <apr_file_io.h>
#include <apr_tables.h>
#include "util_script.h"



/* Define prototypes of our functions in this module */
typedef struct {
    const char *key;
    const char *value;
} keyValuePair;

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool);
static int example_handler(request_rec *r);
keyValuePair *readPost(request_rec *r);

/* Define our module as an entity and assign a function for registering hooks  */

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA   example_module =
{
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,            // Per-directory configuration handler
    NULL,            // Merge handler for per-directory configurations
    NULL,            // Per-server configuration handler
    NULL,            // Merge handler for per-server configurations
    NULL,            // Any directives we may have for httpd
    register_hooks   // Our hook registering function
};




/* register_hooks: Adds a hook to the httpd process */
static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool) 
{

    /* Hook the request handler */
    ap_hook_handler(example_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_LAST);
}

/* The handler function for our module.
 * This is where all the fun happens!
 */

static int example_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    /* First off, we need to check if this is a call for the "example" handler.
     * If it is, we accept it and do our things, it not, we simply return DECLINED,
     * and Apache will try somewhere else.
     */
    if (!r->handler || strcmp(r->handler, "example-handler")) return (DECLINED);

    // The first thing we will do is write a simple "Hello, world!" back to the client.
    ap_rputs("Hello, world!<br/>", r);
    return OK;
}

keyValuePair *readPost(request_rec *r) {
    apr_array_header_t *pairs = NULL;
    apr_off_t len;
    apr_size_t size;
    int res;
    int i = 0;
    char *buffer;
    keyValuePair *kvp;

    res = ap_parse_form_data(r, NULL, &pairs, -1, HUGE_STRING_LEN);
    if (res != OK || !pairs) return NULL; /* Return NULL if we failed or if there are is no POST data */
    kvp = apr_pcalloc(r->pool, sizeof(keyValuePair) * (pairs->nelts + 1));
    while (pairs && !apr_is_empty_array(pairs)) {
        ap_form_pair_t *pair = (ap_form_pair_t *) apr_array_pop(pairs);
        apr_brigade_length(pair->value, 1, &len);
        size = (apr_size_t) len;
        buffer = apr_palloc(r->pool, size + 1);
        apr_brigade_flatten(pair->value, buffer, &size);
        buffer[len] = 0;
        kvp[i].key = apr_pstrdup(r->pool, pair->name);
        kvp[i].value = buffer;
        ap_rputs(kvp[i].key,r);
        ap_rputs(kvp[i].value,r);
        i++;
    }
    return kvp;
}
```

I have copied the read post function from the apache website:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html#snippets

I get the following error while trying to compile the module:

> mod_example.c:82:9: error: use of undeclared identifier
>   'ap_form_pair_t'
>           ap_form_pair_t *pair = (ap_form_pair_t *) apr_array_pop(pairs);

apxs does not recognize ap_form_pair_t. Am I missing any header file ?

Can you please help me resolve this ?

Comment: Try adding `#include <mod_request.h>` and let us know.

Comment: Hi Sourav, I got mod_request.h header file not found error.

Comment: I am not very sure, i suggested that using a quick Google search. Sorry. Maybe someone experienced can help you out then. :-)

Answer (score 1):

ap_form_pair_t comes with apache version 2.4, so I think you use a lower version.

This function writes all post data in a buffer, it may help you:

```
int util_read(request_rec *r, char **rbuf, size_t &length){

int rc;
length = 0;
if((rc = ap_setup_client_block(r, REQUEST_CHUNKED_ERROR)) != OK){

    return rc;

}

if(ap_should_client_block(r)){
    char argsbuffer[HUGE_STRING_LEN];
    int rsize, len_read, rpos=0;
    length = r->remaining;
    *rbuf = (char*)apr_pcalloc(r->pool, length + 1);


    while((len_read = ap_get_client_block(r, argsbuffer, sizeof(argsbuffer))) > 0){
        if((rpos + len_read) > length){
            rsize = length - rpos;
        } else {
            rsize = len_read;
        }
        memcpy((char*)*rbuf + rpos, argsbuffer, rsize);
        rpos += rsize;
    }

}
return rc;
}
```